# error 1002: 'LMW3SVC/1/ROOT/MyFirstWebsite' is not a well formed IIS metabase path

Tags: asp.net, iis-7.5, web-deployment, iis-metabase

I am trying to learn how to deploy my first website which is physically located here (C:\Users\Amal\Documents\Visual Studio 2008\WebSites\ErrorHandlingTest). I am using instructions from some book. after installing the Internet Information Services on my laptop which has Windows 7 ultimate on it. I added a virtual directory and gave it the alias (MyFirstWebsite). after that  I was able to open the website just by typing
        http://localhost/myfirstwebsite/mypage.aspx
on the address bar of my firefox v.21 browser. 
the book then told me to do some code compilation to the website by using the command-line tool named aspnet_compiler.exe which is supposed to compile my website into binary files after running this command :
aspnet_compiler -m W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyFirstWebsite C:\MyFirstWebsiteDeply

but I got this error:

error 1002: 'W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyFirstWebsite' is not a well formed IIS metabase path.

I use asp.net 3.5 , visual studio 2008 , internet information services version 7.5.7600.16385

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

aspnet_compiler -m LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/MyFirstWebsite -f C:\MyFirstWebsiteDeply

You had missed the "LM" at the start of the metabase path.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the `iispath` should be `/LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT/XXX`.

Pay attention to the '/' at the beginning.